# How to add product price in _productsmallbox in nopCommerce 2.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 2.6. I am using _productsmallbox partial view to display some products on homepage. I just wanted to know how to display the price, discount percentage in this partial view as this uses ProductOverviewModel and this model does not contain discount amount.

Comment: as i know ProductOverviewModel is not Provide Product Price and otherdetail you want, you need to add this price and other fields in ProductOverViewmodel and need to customize in PrepareProductOverview Method in Product Controller then you get this fields.

Answer (score 1):

Now, the current NopCommerce version is 4.5, and I've showed the discount percentage by calculating like below:

```
<span>-@(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal((Model.ProductPrice.OldPriceValue - Model.ProductPrice.PriceValue)/Model.ProductPrice.OldPriceValue*100),2))%</span>
```